# Sold Vile Armor before getting Vile set

Tags: infinity-blade-2

I think I must have sold the Vile Armor and, guess what, now I need it! I've been back to the tree twice but I didn't win it again. It's not in the store either. What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

New Game+ might work. I don't know I havn't sold the vile armor but new game+ resets the whole game except your gold and levels